# Mediaelement.js - not working in Ie6,7 and 8

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have media element working for FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera and IE9 but is not working in Ie6,7,8!

For these browsers I'm seeing just a black box with the same size of the video.

Any idea what is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's falling back and couldn't find the flash file.
Give the right path for flash swf file.
And of course you need flash installed on your browsers.

You can also write onerror: function.
It triggers when both HTML5 and Flash fails.

Comment: Try this page I make out of media element. You'll get some idea. It's all mp4 so it's HTML5 on chrome and Flash fallback on FF and old browsers.

Comment: dev-moeam -dot- hardwarezone -dot- com/videogallerys

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you copy the build folder in the mediaelement download into your web dir and reference the css and swf file in there. The reason your seeing a black box in IE is probably because its trying to find some files from build folder do do its flash stuff and its not there. Rename build to something like mediaelement or something.

These two files need to be loaded from the build dir

```
<script src="build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
```